# Как убрать редирект на https в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
allow from all
deny from 104.
deny from 94.
deny from 185.
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалите строки

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Может первую строку `Rewrite Engine On` не надо удалять? Она же ничем не вредит.

Comment: Если у вас нет других команд `RewriteCond/RewriteRule`, она не нужна.

Comment: Теперь Сайт http:// пока не может обработать этот запрос.

Comment: В консоли пишет GET http://site/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @vadimuha, а в логе ошибок на сервере что пишет?